# Is there any PHP performance issue in export to CSV or excel

Tags: php

am exporting huge data to excel using php.

i change that to csv and text.

i see no difference in file size.

So PHP performance have anything to do with file format.

even if file format is different , rows and columns is same.
consider 60 column and 100000 rows.

is there any optimizing technique,other than  ini memory limit and execution time.
we have to taken care

Comment: How are you exporting to Excel? I'd expect to see quite significant differences between CSV, XLS and XLSX file sizes. And it's quite difficult to give you any performance tops without knowing how you're doing the exports

Comment: how means... am getting data array from stored procedure and i am

Comment: printing using php tab seperated with header and content type as xls or csv

Comment: That explains why there's no difference in file size at all. You're simply creating a tab-separated value file and setting the content type in the header.... this doesn't automatically convert your tab-separated to an Excel file

Comment: header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename
 header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

Comment: he only difference is in the abve two lines and ..xls is tab seperated and csv is comma seperated..

Comment: I hope you're using fputcsv for writing your file rather than building it by hand using string concatenation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the various Excel libraries for PHP will build the spreadsheet in-memory, which could cause problems for very large data sets. CSV/txt, on the other hand, can be written out to disk or the client for each row, so memory usage is minimal.

Performance-wise, the Excel libraries will always have larger overhead. There's all kinds of extra Excel-specific binary bits in the file which need special handling in PHP, whereas CSV is just plain text. PHP's core purpose is to be able to spit out large amounts of text very quickly, so generating csv/txt is going to be faster, always. And of  course, there's function call over head. In pseudo code, consider the difference between:

CSV:

```
echo "$column1, $column2, $column3, $column4";
```

versus Excel:

```
$workbook->write('A1', $column1);
$workbook->write('B1', $column2);
$workbook->write('C1', $column3);
$workbook->write('D1', $column3);

etc...
```

On the plus side for Excel, particularly with XLSX, there is some compression so the same amount of data will take up less space. This can be mitigated somewhat by using compression in the webserver, or feeding the CSV/txt output into a Zip library server-side.

Comment: ok so ... i am creating a file , can be call it as CSV..only.

Comment: not xls...but looks like xls and extension only. its like fake xls :) amnot going to create real xls anyway as it wil be more load.        Thanks Marc  for  response and knowledge transfer

Comment: You can create a CSV file, call it `whatever.xls` and Excel will load it. You would have to re-save it as a real Excel file, though, if you want to use any formatting/formulas, or multiple workbooks, none of which a plain CSV file supports.

Comment: As you say, there would be a big memory overhead using any of the Excel libraries for PHP... the only one that I'm aware isn't purely in-memory is a closed-source commercial product, though I need to take a closer look at Ilia Alshanetsky's  http://github.com/iliaal/php_excel

Comment: as i saw you are an excellent in excel :)  .. u have any suggestion that i can do with php ini or php or anything when i export 1 million or more records.is there any limit for csv file, that it can hold..

Comment: The only real limit for a CSV file is disk space: but Excel 95+ (xls files) can read a maximum of 65536 lines, while Excel 2007+ (xlsx files) is limited to 1 million lines... so CSV files larger than that can't be read fully by Excel, which will simply discard the remaining lines.